# Unity - Walk around a cube

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an issue with trying to get an 'object(character)' to walk around a cube (all sides) within Unity. Ive attached an image and video showing what i am trying to achieve. Im trying to show you visually rather than trying to explain. As the character drops over the edge it rotates 90 degrees and then the stands up like gravity has switched. Then the character can jump walk etc.

[This is an example of someone else that posted a video showing exactly what im trying to achieve](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYlGJoLUJVQ)

I have looked through the forums and cant find what im after. i have tried to attach a diagram but the site wont let me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Nick

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: ok my bad, didn't realise when tagging.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that I can think of.

One is to trigger the gravity change when the character exits one face of the cube to go to another. To achieve this you would have trigger zones on each edge and face and use a `[Bob went from Face A to Edge ANorth -> Switch Gravity to go in X direction]`.

This would work for situations where the gravity switch must affect other objects too but be advantageous to your player (walking off the side makes an enemy fall off and die - for example.)

However, if you want all entities to stick to their relative sides then we need to make custom gravity! To do this is easier than you might think as gravity is simply a downward accelleration of 9.8. So turn off the engines native gravity and create a "personal gravity" component:

```
private Vector3 surfaceNormal;
private Vector3 personalNormal;
private float personalGravity = 9.8f;
private float normalSwitchRange = 5.0f;

public void Start()
{    
    personalNormal = transform.up; // Start with "normal" normal
    rigidbody.freezeRotation = true; // turn off physics rotation    
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Apply force taking into account character normal as personal gravity:
    rigidbody.AddForce(-personalGravity * rigidbody.mass * personalNormal);
}
```

Rotating your character and changing his normal is then up to you to suit your situation or game mechanic, whether you do that by raycasting if you're standing on a surface to detect when to change it or only want gravity to change when you hit a powerup or similar - experiment and see what works. Comment more if you have questions!

EDIT:

As an addition to the video you linked. You can keep a state variable on the jump state and raycast in each axis direction to check which face is nearest in the case of just rolling off.

```
public void Update()
{
    // we don't update personal normals in the case of jumping
    if(!jumping)
    {
        UpdatePersonalNormal();
    }

}

public void UpdatePersonalNormal()
{
    RaycastHit hit; //hit register
    // list of valid normals to check (all 6 axis)
    Ray[] rays = 
        {
        Vector3.up, Vector3.down, 
        Vector3.left, Vector3.right, 
        Vector3.forward, Vector3.backward
        };

    //for each valid normal...
    foreach(Ray rayDirection in rays)
    {
        //check if we are near a cube face...
        if(Physics.Raycast(rayDirection , hit, normalSwitchRange)
        {
             personalNormal = hit.Normal; //set personal normal ...
             return; // and return as we are done
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that the above is completely hand written and not tested but play with it and this pseudo start should give you a good idea of what to do.

Comment: Hi Blue, Yes i understand what you are saying. I want the character to be able to act like the game Kula World [link](http://s.uvlist.net/l/y2010/07/72628.jpg). The Character can walk on all sides of cube as well as enemies. But id the character jumps platforms (cubes) then the character will fall. I think this wont be able to be achieved if the engines native gravity is turned off will this affect it doing so?

Comment: Okay so if I jump and I am on the side face do I fall or just jump on that particular axis? You can make a check on the current personal normal and make the character fall if they are not "upright" by switching the normal back to up. Making gravity cause them to fall.

Comment: To undertand more i have uploaded a video to my Dropbox. Basically before i moved over to Unity someone made a demo which acted the way i wanted in Blender (written in Python). I made the video to show you the actions of the character. Also I can send you the Blender file if you want? or code? [link to video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rx55rf32jvjv8e/test.avi) Thanks, Nick

Comment: Great video - shows each state I needed to see. You can use the above to that effect by choosing when the normal is to be switched. For example when running off an edge you can switch the normal to be the appropriate face, but when jump state is active the normals wont switch. This way your jump and gravity will work with the normal that is active (meaning you CAN jump on the sides of the cube) bu won't switch when in jump state so you can jump OFF a cube as well.

Comment: I have edited my answer to elaborate on the functions you might make.

Comment: Oh i understand your point but im lost with how to build it as im a beginner with C# and Javascript. So for everything else but have know idea how to implement ontop of your code yet :( would you mind sending me a demo? I could pay you? really desperate to understand the logic behind what im trying to achieve. No worries if not.

Comment: Ive tried your code but there is an error '(28,5): error CS0230: Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement'

Comment: foreach(Ray rayDirection in rays) - edited my answer - like I said it was hand written so there will be mistakes :P

Comment: its ok, there are more errors i cant seem to fix now. I know you have hand written it. Im just going to have to give up for the moment as unless i can get a demo i will take forever to put it together. thanks again.

Comment: Post your code to a drop box and message me that. I'll take a closer look later.

Comment: thankyou! Greatly appreciated! All i have setup is a cube with a cube character. thought it would be better to upload project than just code? [link to File] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6radyilf30mye7/Test.zip)

Comment: hey Blue, any luck with testing? Im trying various guides again but getting frustrated with myself now lol.